# Yii get pagesize in view of ClistView

Tags: php, yii

How would i get the current pagesize in my View? I want to be able to add a banner when half the pagesize is reached.

If the page size is 10, insert a banner at position 5

i tried adding this in my `view.php`

```
if ($index == ($dataProvider->pagination->pageSize / 2)) { ... }
```

and this my `index.php`

```
$this->widget ( 'site.common.extensions.EListView.EListView', array (
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemView' => '_view_gallery',
        'pagerCssClass' => 'pagination',
        'template' => '
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="pull-right">{sorter}</div>
                        <div class="pull-left"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">{items}</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row padding-top-20px">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        {pager}
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div></div>',
        'pager' => array (
                'id' => '_pagination',
                'class' => 'LinkPager',
                'header' => '',
                'htmlOptions' => array (
                        'class' => 'pagination'
                )
        ),
        'emptyText' => '<div class="alert alert-info">No result found.</div>'
    )
);
```

but nothing happens.

I'm currently using this extension to create a perpage page size.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/elistview

also tried without using this extension, but still no luck. **I'm using Yii 1.1.16**.

any ideas?

Comment: i could just do this in my view `$pageSize = (!empty($_GET['pageSize'])) ? $_GET['pageSize'] : 10;` but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your _view_gallery.php you can use special variables available for CListView and CGridView (http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/252/special-variables-in-cgridview-and-clistview/) in order to get the pageSize.

That could look like this:

```
if($widget->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize == 10){
  //do something here
}
```

Accessing $dataProvider directly won't result in anything because that variable means nothing to the view.